# Why can't we create objects for an abstract class in C++?

Tags: c++, object, abstract-class

I know it is not allowed in C++, but why? What if it was allowed, what would the problems be?

Comment: Obviously there is a gap in communication somewhere. Could you give a code example and your high-level goal?

Comment: @GMan I dint come across this while writing some code. I just want to know the concrete reason as to why we cannot create an object for an abstract class? Is the problem concerned with memory allocation, or is it concerned with something else? and what exactly is the problem? Thats my whole point here.

Comment: Because it is not logical to allow it. It's like asking XXX (pick your deity here) to create an animal (an instance). That's just not possible he/she/it has to create a specific type of Animal (like a 'Duck': An instance of the class Duck). The concept of Animal is Abstract there are no objects that are just Animals.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Judging by your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091495/does-new-allocate-memory-for-the-functions-of-a-class-also), it seems you don't understand how classes operate. Classes are a collection of functions which operate on data.

Functions themselves contain no memory in a class. The following class:

```
struct dumb_class
{
    void foo(){}
    void bar(){}
    void baz(){}
    // .. for all eternity

    int i;
};
```

Has a size of `int`. No matter how many functions you have ever, this class will only take up the space it takes to operate on an `int`. When you call a function in this class, the compiler will pass you a pointer to the place where the data in the class is stored; this is the `this` pointer.

So, the function lie in memory somewhere, loaded once at the beginning of your program, and wait to be called with data to operate on.

Virtual functions are different. The C++ standard does *not* mandate how the behavior of the virtual functions should go about, only what that behavior should be. Typically, implementations use what's called a virtual table, or vtable for short. A vtable is a table of function pointers, which like normal functions, only get allocated once.

Take this class, and assume our implementor uses vtables:

```
struct base { virtual void foo(void); };
struct derived { virtual void foo(void); };
```

The compiler will need to make two vtables, one for base and one for derived. They will look something like this:

```
typedef /* some generic function pointer type */ func_ptr;

func_ptr __baseTable[] = {&base::foo}; 
func_ptr __derivedTable[] = {&derived::foo};
```

How does it use this table? When you create an instance of a class above, the compiler slips in a hidden pointer, which will point to the correct vtable. So when you say:

```
derived d;
base* b = &d;
b->foo();
```

Upon executing the last line, it goes to the correct table (`__derivedTable` in this case), goes to the correct index (0 in this case), and calls that function. As you can see, that will end up calling `derived::foo`, which is exactly what should happen.

Note, for later, this is the same as doing `derived::foo(b)`, passing `b` as the `this` pointer.

So, when virtual methods are present, the class of the size will increase by one pointer (the pointer to the vtable.) Multiple inheritance changes this a bit, but it's mostly the same. You can get more details at [C++-FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html).

Now, to your question. I have:

```
struct base { virtual void foo(void) = 0; }; // notice the = 0
struct derived { virtual void foo(void); };
```

and `base::foo` has no implementation. This makes `base::foo` a pure abstract function. So, if I were to call it, like above:

```
derived d;
base* b = &d;
base::foo(b);
```

What behavior should we expect? Being a pure virtual method, `base::foo` doesn't even exist. The above code is undefined behavior, and could do anything from nothing to crashing, with anything in between. (Or worse.)

Think about what a pure abstract function represents. Remember, functions take no data, they only describe how to manipulate data. A pure abstract function says: "I want to call this method and have my data be manipulated. How you do this is up to you."

So when you say, "Well, let's call an abstract method", you're replying to the above with: "Up to me? No, you do it." to which it will reply "@#^@#^". It simply doesn't make sense to tell someone who's saying "do this", "no."

To answer your question directly:

> "why we cannot create an object for an abstract class?"

Hopefully you see now, abstract classes only define the functionality the concrete class should be able to do. The abstract class itself is only a blue-print; you don't live in blue-prints, you live in houses that implement the blue-prints.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is simply this:

- what should the program do when an abstract **method** is called?
- and even worse: what should be returned for a non-void **function**?

The application whould proabably have to crash or thow a runtime exception and thus this would cause trouble. You can't dummy-implement every abstract function.

Answer (score 3):

A class can simply be declared abstract where it has no abstract methods. I guess that could be instantiated in theory but the class designer doesn't want you to. It may have unintended consequences.

Usually however abstract classes have abstract methods. They can't be instantiated for the simple reason that they're missing those methods.

Comment: Yes, what "unintended consequences" are possible? Suppose I guarantee that my object will never call any of its functions?

Comment: By declaring a method a class has made a contract tos ay that you can call that method. The class contract will describe what that function does, what arguments it takes and what it returns (if anything). An abstract class wouldn't be able to fulfill that contract.

Comment: If you make a method `abstract` you expect it *must* be implemented by its subclass, and want the compiler to catch errors for you when that method is called not via a subclass. If you don't require that method to be called, simply leave it out or supply a default implementation.

Comment: @cletus Yes, I totally understand that. Suppose I decide to redesign C++ so that I can create objects for abstract classes. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: @KennyTM for a moment, just forget the logic. What I want to know is whether it is possible at all?

Comment: Anything is possible if you make up the rules.

Comment: @KennyTM do you have a reason WHY?

Comment: @GMan thats what I want to know: if I "make up the rules", is it possible?

Comment: @cambr: C++ is a statically (and strongly) typed language. Of course you could design a language that works different. For example, Javascript is loosely and dynamically typed and it has first class functions so you can at runtime add methods to a class or to a particular object (or take them away even). As a result Javascript has no abstract classes because the concept doesn't make sense in that context. It does in C++ however.

Comment: @cambr: I've explained a few comments above.

Answer (score 3):

Because logically it does not make any sense.

An abstract class is a description that is incomplete.
It indicates what things need to be filled out to make it complete but without those bits its not complete.

My first example was a chess game:
The game has lots of pieces of different type (King,Queen,Pawn ... etc).

But there are no actual objects of type piece, but all objects are instances of objects derived from piece. How can you have an object of something that is not fully defined. There is not point in creating an object of piece as the game does not know how it moves (that is the abstract part). It knows it can move but not how it does it.

Answer (score 2):

Abstract classes are non-instantiable *by definition*.  They require that there be derived, concrete classes.  What else would an abstract class be if it didn't have pure virtual (unimplemented) functions?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same class of question as why can't I change the value of a const variable, why can't I access private class members from other classes or why can't I override final methods.

Because that's the purpose of these keywords, to prevent you from doing so. Because the author of the code deemed doing so dangerous, undesired or simply impossible due to some abstract reasons like lack of essential functions that need to be added by specific child classes. It isn't really that you can't instantiate because a class is virtual. It's that inability to instantiate a class defines it as virtual (and if a class that can't be instantiated isn't virtual, it's an error. Same goes the other way, if instance of given class makes sense, it shouldn't be marked as virtual)

Answer (score 1):

Why we cant create an object of an abstract class?

simply abstract class contains abstract methods(means the functions which are without the body) and we cannot give functionality to the abstract methods. And if we try to give functionality to the abstract methods then there will be no difference between abstract class and virtual class. So lastly if we create an object Of an abstrast class then there is no fun to call the useless functions or abstract methods as they are without the functionality..so thats why any language doesnt allow us to create an object of an abstract class..

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything to the answer accepted in... 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes instantiated would be pretty useless, because you would be seeing a lot more of "pure virtual function called". :)

It's like: we all know that a car would have 3 pedals and a steering wheel and a gear stick. Now, if that would be it, and there'd be an instance of 3 pedals and gear stick and a wheel, I'm not buying it, I want a car, like with seats, doors, AC etc. with pedals actually doing something apart from being in existence and that's what abstract class doesn't promise me, the ones *implementing* it do.

Answer (score 0):

Basically creation of object is responsible for allocation of memory for member variables and member functions. but here, in pure virtual function we have declaration and defination in derived class.so creation of object generates error.